# Apply replace to all columns of SQL server query

Tags: sql-server, replace

I know how to replace something in one field:

```
Select Replace(Clmn1, char(9), ' ') as Clmn1
From TableA
```

Now I would like to apply replace statement to all columns in the table. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: probably just as easy repeating that for each column as it is looking at sys.tables and sys.columns, joining, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no shortcut here (short of dynamic sql, but you dont want to do that!)

```
Select Replace(Clmn1, char(9), ' ') as Clmn1,
       Replace(Clmn2, char(9), ' ') as Clmn2,
       Replace(Clmn3, char(9), ' ') as Clmn3
From TableA
```

If this is something you do often, you could write a user defined function, which would slightly shorten your statement

```
Select dbo.CleanChar9(Clmn1) as Clmn1,
       dbo.CleanChar9(Clmn2) as Clmn2,
       dbo.CleanChar9(Clmn3) as Clmn3
From TableA
```

with

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanChar9( @val NVARCHAR(MAX) ) -- use the appropriate type
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(@val,CHAR(9), ' ');
END
```

Comment: Except that scalar functions are horrible for performance. This would be calling that scalar function for every column of every row. Ugh.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, yes they are. I was thinking that as I wrote this. I probably should have mentioned it.